# Angular 5 - Populate Options In mat-select With Objects? Not With NgFor?

Tags: angular, angular-material

NgFor populates a dropdown or list by iterating through an array.  However, Observables give us a stream of data, in my case objects, that is already "iterated".  Why loop? Just get to work making options.

```
{skill_id: 8, skill_name: "Whatever"}
{skill_id: 9, skill_name: "Something"}
```

It seems that I shouldn't need an array when I have such a nice stream of objects that should replace NgFor.  I'm thinking something like this and creating a new option as objects are received from the Observable:

```
<mat-select  placeholder="Select one">
    <mat-option (click)="loadIdValueInForm(skill_id)"
                    [value]="skill_name">{{skill_name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

There are a variety of older posts that do this in various ways from an array of objects, but it would be better if we could do it with the results of a common Observable setup.  Any ideas?  Anyone creative about this?

```
private getListData(dbTable) {
    this.skills$ = this.httpService.getDropDownList(dbTable)
      .map(data => data.resource)
      .switchMap(data => data)
```

Comment: May I know the reason behind not to use ngFor?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over an observable, you can use the `async` pipe for that.

In your example:

```
<mat-option (click)="loadIdValueInForm(skill_id)"
                    *ngFor="let skill of skills$ | async"
                    [value]="skill.skill_name">{{skill_name}}
    </mat-option>
```

Then you can remove the following part from your code:

```
.map(data => data.resource)
```

Comment: Thanks @TheUnreal but I have the async pipe and it puts objects into the select element and NgFor logs an error.  This isn't above because my question isn't about that, but it is in my code and a well recognized issue.  Many SO posts trying to find a decent solution but mostly hack answers.  Also, I have to get to the data objects which are inside of the resource object delivered by Postgres.  NgFor wants an array but not an array of key value objects.  Life would be easier for a lot of devs if it did.

Comment: You can use `[ngValue]="skill"` if you want "store" the whole object. And yes, you can use the async pipe. Note: is the `switchMap` you need remove, not the map